# How to get earliest date and latest date from a Date Column which has values in the format "01/01/2019 09:01:00 AM"?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column in excel with date in the given below format.

When I read the data using worksheet.cells(row, col) it is in string format

8/10/2019  9:01:00 AM
8/6/2019  9:01:00 AM
8/22/2019  9:01:00 AM
8/18/2019  9:01:00 AM
8/14/2019  9:01:00 AM

Objective is to get the earliest date and latest date and use those to filter in another excel.

Is there a simpler way to get the two dates from the date column?

For the above example I want the earliestDate = 08/06/2019 and latestDate = 08/22/2019

I don't use VBA extensively, this is the first time I am using and I am updating an existing VBA code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say the date-like strings are in cells `A1:A10` (for example).

---

**Using array formulas**

Entering the formulas below with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER should get you smallest and largest dates respectively.

```
=MIN(DATEVALUE(A1:A10))
=MAX(DATEVALUE(A1:A10))
```

**Using VBA**

```
Option Explicit

Sub MinAndMaxDates()
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Set sourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    Dim inputArray() As Variant
    inputArray = sourceSheet.Range("A1:A10") ' For example

    Dim smallestDate As Date
    smallestDate = CDate(inputArray(1, 1))

    Dim largestDate As Date

    Dim rowIndex As Long
    For rowIndex = LBound(inputArray, 1) To UBound(inputArray, 1)
        inputArray(rowIndex, 1) = CDate(inputArray(rowIndex, 1)) ' Or could use DateValue
        smallestDate = Application.Min(smallestDate, inputArray(rowIndex, 1))
        largestDate = Application.Max(largestDate, inputArray(rowIndex, 1))
    Next rowIndex
End Sub
```

Unless you're dealing with a huge amount of dates, the above should be fine. If not, then the loop's internal logic can be improved.

(It is not possible that `smallestDate` and `largestDate` will both be assigned/changed during the same loop iteration, so they should be on separate (mutually exclusive) branches using an `If-Elseif-End If` instead of functions `Max` and `Min`. That way the current date is only compared once.)